# How to get links from page - BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just want the href/links for each of the blocks for the page, but it is producing blank

Here is my code so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
lists=[]
baseurl='https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/'
for x in range (1,5):
    url=f'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/results?meetingView=2020%20ASCO%20Virtual%20Scientific%20Program&page={x}'
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    productlist=soup.find_all('a',class_='ng-star-inserted')
    for item in productlist:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer:**

The reason it's not giving any results is because the target website uses JavaScript to render content whereas BeautifulSoup doesn't process JavaScript but just works on plain HTML. To scrape JavaScript Rendered Pages you need something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

**Old Answer:**

You can use [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select `a` tags which has `href` property defined and to do that using BeautifulSoup you can use [`select` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) as follows:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
lists=[]
baseurl='https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/'
for x in range (1,5):
    url=f'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/results?meetingView=2020%20ASCO%20Virtual%20Scientific%20Program&page={x}'
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    productlist=soup.select('a[href].ng-star-inserted')
    for item in productlist:
        print(item.attr.get("href"))
```

Comment: This printed blank/nothing for me, did it print href for you?

Comment: @VoidS After checking the website in question, I have updated the answer